# How can I loop through creating Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, properties

Below is what the code looks like right now, with less rows and less properties.

```
var row1 = new Object();
var row2 = new Object();
var row3 = new Object();
var row4 = new Object();
var row5 = new Object();
var row6 = new Object();
var row7 = new Object();
row1.name = "Hello World!";
alert (row1.name);
```

This code below doesn't work as intended because row isn't primitive, but I need to do something like this because I have a billion row variables.

```
var row = [];
var row1 = [];
var row2 = [];
var row3 = [];
row.push(1); 
row[1].name = "Hello World";
alert(row[1].name);
```

How can I do this, if at all possible?

Comment: 1 billion row variables?? Not sure javascript will handle that many objects. Do you just need an array of objects? Sample 1 should work. In the second code sample your pushing an integer to an array. Then attempting to add a property. integers cannot have additional properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rows = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{        
    rows.push(new Object());
}
rows[0].name = "Hello World!";
alert(rows[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom complex objects in javascript like this:

```
//complex object
ComplexObj = function(){
    var self = {
        'prop1': 'value1',
        'prop2': 'value2',
        'prop3': {
            'subprop1': 'subvalue1',
            'subprop2': 'subvalue2'
        },
        'prop4': [
            1, 2, 3, 4
        ]
    };

    return self;
};

//code that creates instances of the complex object
var rows = [];
var newObj1 = new ComplexObj();
newObj1.prop1 = 'newvalue1';

var newObj2 = new ComplexObj();
newObj2.prop3.subprop2 = 'newsubvalue2';

rows.push(newObj1);
rows.push(newObj2);

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    alert('row' + i + ': prop1=' + rows[i].prop1 + ' subprop2=' + rows[i].prop3.subprop2);
}
```

You can view the demo here. Notice that I update newObj1.prop1 and newObj2.prop3.subprop2 to show that newObj1 and newObj2 are different instances of ComplexObj.

http://jsfiddle.net/p5evg/1/